# Write objects to json file?

Tags: php, file, validation, json

I have a problem: I need to write some objects that are in json format in a file, but in such a way that it would eventually result a valid json. Now it would be simple to make an array with them and then encode them, **but** the problem is that I get each element in a different .php page when some event is dispatched, and I need to pass them all to a single **valid** json.
Does anyone have any idea how would this be done?

---

Edit:
What I have is a Facebook app and I get user data and write it to a json file, however for most of the user's data, I need to request permissions. Also, each of the .php pages is for one type of data (one for groups, one for posting photos etc) and the user can choose what data he/she wants to be written in the json. It's not a good idea to ask for **all** permissions when entering the app, because users are likely to cancel entering apps that request many permissions. Instead, each time the user chooses to add some more data to the json, I will ask for the perms for that type of data.
At the end, when the user clicks a button I will write all the data to the json. I write everything with `json_encode`

---

Edit2: An approach I've been thinking of is to write all the data to the json, open it for reading, change all `][` to `,` and write back to the json. However, that might be an inefficient approach, since my file will be on a cloud, and opening and closing the file might cost some time

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  If you have a collection of objects, you can JSON encode them, write them to a file, and then the individual PHP pages can decode the JSON in the file, and pick out the object that it's interested in--but it sounds like you don't want to do that for some reason?  Also, if I correctly understand your scenario, it sounds like a good situation to store the data in a database rather than stuffing it all in one file, so each PHP script needs to decode the entire slew of objects when it only wants one particular object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more Information here, because the answer may change based on ether you'r using regular PHP or OOP PHP.

- In the second case(OOP PHP) you can make a global array and fill it with the correct elements and when (in your code) you reach a complete object you can write your file.
- In the first case(regular PHP) I think you can use a hidden input and post the variables from a page to the other...

Any way an example code would give more information on what you want to achieve here so the proper help could be provided.
Hope this help.